# App Widget problems on API 25

Tags: android

My app contains an App Widget composed of two parts: a header and a list view collection. Both parts are updated at the same time by pressing a button on the app.

On the widget update, I call **updateAppWidget** and **notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged** to update the header and the collection respectively. So far, nothing out of the ordinary.

This has been working correctly from API 15 to API 24. But now, **on API 25** (Previews 1 and 2 received OTA on a Nexus 5X), something weird happens: **the widget randomly doesn't update when I press the button**.

I've been debugging and the problem seems to come from calling notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged immediately after updateAppWidget. When I put a delay between the two calls, the issue never happens.

It's as if those methods would clash on API 25. But as the source code for the preview hasn't been published yet, I cannot see what's happening inside.

- Has anyone experienced similar problems?
- Am I doing wrong by calling notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged after updateAppWidget on the same call? Should I do it in a different way?

Comment: You might switch to a different home screen implementation and see if the problem occurs there too. It's possible this is more an issue with the home screen than with Android itself.

Comment: @CommonsWare You are right. I installed Nova Launcher, made several tests and the issue doesn't happen there. Does this mean Google Now Launcher could have a bug on API 25? How can I verify it?

Comment: "Does this mean Google Now Launcher could have a bug on API 25?" -- that would be my guess, given your description. "How can I verify it?" -- I don't know if anyone has created an `AppWidgetHost` that can serve as a test harness for confirming app widget behavior. I'm not 100% certain that's even possible. Outside of that, and beyond just trying a few home screens, I don't have any good ideas.

Comment: @CommonsWare I've opened an issue on the issue tracker and attached a sample app. Let's see what they say. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=228575

Comment: The same issue is happening on a Nexus 9 with the final 7.1.1 OTA version received today (build NMF26F). I guess I'll have to start looking for a hacky workaround.

Comment: For the moment the only viable solution I've found is to put a delay of 1 second between the call to updateAppWidget and the call to notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged (I did this using a delayed runnable for the latter). This works, but feels very wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the issue I opened on the issue tracker has been marked as 'FutureRelease', so it actually seems there was a problem with the Android implementation or the Google Launcher:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=228575

As I explained in a comment, the workaround that can be used in the meantime is adding a 1 second delay between the call to updateAppWidget and the call to notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged (using a delayed runnable for the latter).